# Dovecot: virtual and local users homonyms: Mail access for users with UID 1000 not permitted

Tags: linux, email, postfix, dovecot

Well, the case seems simple but I can’t find a satisfactory answer.

I have a Postfix/Dovecot installation with the later configured to work with virtual emails which works like a charm... for virtual users who do not have an account on the server.

To make things clearer, let’s pick an example: `virtualuser` is registered in the virtual users’ database (/etc/dovecot/users) and is able to receive and send mails through IMAP and SMTP without any problems. On the other hand, `localuser` is a regular system user on the server. Now, if I add a new user in the Dovecot’s virtual users database named `localuser` and try to connect as this virtual-user-with-a-local-alias in IMAP, I get the following error in my logs:

```
imap: Error: user localuser: Mail access for users with UID 1000 not permitted ([etc]).
```

It is clear that since Postfix finds a user named `localuser` in the system users, it tries to authenticates with *that* user and doesn’t even looks at the virtual users.

So here is the question: how do I have Postfix lookup virtual users **before** local users?

Is this even possible or am I stuck with a messy configuration mixing [local and virtual users](https://serverfault.com/questions/659846/postfix-with-dovecot-local-and-virtual-users)?

Comment: This log message `imap: Error: XXXX`  was part of dovecot error message. Postfix only do SMTP not IMAP nor POP3

Comment: Thanks for the precision! Same question replacing postfix with dovecot then!

Comment: Have you considered keeping OS users IMAP/SMTP logins "domain less" and make virtusers IMAP/SMTP logins "domanized"?

Comment: @Andrzej: given the small size of the server (few tens of users at most), this is not an option for me.

Comment: Please don't include the solution in the question. Instead, you need put the solution in the answer section below.

Comment: @masegaloeh: totally right, don't know what I had in mind when doing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I expected, the solution to this was *tremendously simple*: `/etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-auth.conf` includes two files: `auth-system.conf.ext` for system users, and `auth-mydomain.conf.ext` for virtual users. The **order** these files are included is important important, system users lookup after virtual users is easily performed by swapping both lines:

```
[...]
!include auth-mydomain.conf.ext
!include auth-system.conf.ext
```